# How to conditionally render Table and change condition variable after plotly_click in R:shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to write an app that conditionally appends 2 tables from points clicked in a `ggplotly` plot, based on whether a count variable is even or odd. Basically, with each clicked point, I need it to alternate between the tables. Right now I'm getting stuck in a loop as when I change the count variable it ping-pongs back and forth between the two `renderTable()` calls instead of waiting for the next click. I'm not sure how to implement it correctly. I think I may need to put the `plotly_click` and the conditional changes to my two save dataframes as an ifelse outside `renderTable()`, possibly inside an `observeEvent`(?), but I wasn't sure how the code would need to look then. I'm completely new to programming with shiny.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

df<-data.frame(x=seq(1:10),y=sample(1:20,10))
d_save <- data.frame()
d_save2 <-data.frame()

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  column(6,tableOutput("dataTable")),
  column(6,tableOutput("dataTable2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    (df%>%ggplot(.,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point())%>%ggplotly()
  })
  
  vals<-reactiveValues(count=1)
  
  output$dataTable <- renderTable({
    if((vals$count %% 2)==1){
      d <- req(event_data("plotly_click"))
      d_save <<- rbind(d_save, d[2:4])
      vals$count<-vals$count+1
    }    
    d_save
  })
  
  output$dataTable2 <- renderTable({    
    if((vals$count %% 2)==0){
      d <- req(event_data("plotly_click"))
      d_save2 <<- rbind(d_save2, d[2:4])
      vals$count<-vals$count+1
    }
    d_save2
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Each `renderTable` reacts to a change in `vals$count` because `vals$count` is reactive.  That's your fundamental issue.  "Basically, with each clicked point, I need it to alternate between the tables.": I don't understand what this means, so I can't offer a concrete solution.  However, a good place to start would be to separate the updating of `d_save` and `d_save2` from their rendition in the UI.  Depending on what you mean by "alternate between the tables", you may be able to replace these to objects with a single reactive.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is missing a closing brace (`}`).  It's not clear if it is missing from your `observeEvent` or the server function itself, but the indentation suggests it's missing from the `observeEvent`.  If that is correct, then you have nested your `renderTable` definitions inside the `observeEvent`.

It works here, but I think you're lucky.  Nesting reactives and observers is almost always a bad idea.  And, personally, I feel it is less clear than alternatives even when it works.

As merely a point of style, since you're flipping between two datasets, you can make `vals$count` a Boolean.  I've renamed it to `vals$use_d_save` to make the intent clearer.

If you make `d_save` and `d_save_2` elements of `vals`, you can avoid the global assignment operator, which is generally considered to be good practice.

Here's a slight variation on your solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

df<-data.frame(x=seq(1:10),y=sample(1:20,10))
d_save <- data.frame()
d_save2 <-data.frame()

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  column(6,tableOutput("dataTable")),
  column(6,tableOutput("dataTable2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    (df%>%ggplot(.,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point())%>%ggplotly()
  })
    
  vals<-reactiveValues(
    use_d_save = TRUE,
    d_save = data.frame(),
    d_save2 = data.frame()
  )
    
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click"), {
    d <- req(event_data("plotly_click"))
    d$x <- as.character(d$x)
    if (vals$use_d_save) {
      vals$d_save <- rbind(vals$d_save, d[2:4])
    } else {
      vals$d_save2 <- rbind(vals$d_save2, d[2:4])            
    }
    vals$use_d_save <- !vals$use_d_save
  })
      
  output$dataTable <- renderTable({
    vals$d_save
  })
      
  output$dataTable2 <- renderTable({
    vals$d_save2
  })
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, the missing (```}```) went missing upon copy&paste, but I did have the ```renderTable()``` inside the ```observeEvent()```. I didn't know how to make it work otherwise. I need data_save and data_save2 to be accessible outside shinyApp, hence why I did the global assignment instead of define them as reactive variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. As I'm completely new to shiny, please let me know if there are any fundamental issues. This is obviously a very basic component of something that eventually will be a bit more complex.

```
df<-data.frame(x=seq(1:10),y=sample(1:20,10))
d_save <- data.frame()
d_save2 <-data.frame()

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  column(6,tableOutput("dataTable")),
  column(6,tableOutput("dataTable2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    (df%>%ggplot(.,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point())%>%ggplotly()
  })
  
  
  vals<-reactiveValues(count=1)
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click"),{
          d <- req(event_data("plotly_click"))
          d$x <- as.character(d$x)
          if((vals$count %% 2)==1){
            d_save <<- rbind(d_save, d[2:4])
          }else{
            d_save2 <<- rbind(d_save2, d[2:4])            
          }
          vals$count<-vals$count+1

    output$dataTable <- renderTable({
      (d_save)
    })
  
    output$dataTable2 <- renderTable({
      (d_save2)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Shiny Plotly]